# Find out the localized names of standard buttons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, localization

In JavaScript, how can I know the name of OK, Cancel, etc. buttons on the standard dialogs?

I want to do the following:

```
confirm ('Press ' + name('OK') + ' to proceed or ' + name('Cancel') + ' to cancel');
```

so that for different users, this would be shown as:

```
'Press OK to proceed or Cancel to cancel'

'Press Aceptar to proceed or Cancelar to cancel'

'Press Да to proceed or Отмена to cancel'
```

etc., according to their language, so that what I say would match the button names that they will really see.

Note: I do not want to change the names of the buttons, I only want to use in my generated string the same names that the browser will show in standard dialogs.

Note: These are not the names that the OS uses but the ones that the browser uses, which are different: one can have a Spanish OS `("Aceptar"/"Cancelar")` but English version of Firefox `("OK"/"Cancel")`, or French version, or whatever.

Comment: like most good questions, i don't think this one has a simple answer. it's probably best to use a html modal dialog in this case (and in general).

Comment: Not a duplicate; this question asks how to find out the localized names in the system, not how to use your localizations for buttons.

Comment: @dandavis: a generated dialog is not a solution: I want the users to see the names for the buttons that they normally see in their browser: if you normally see your "OK" in Hindi, I want to show you "OK" in Hindi. But then we return to the same question: I will need to find out what your normal "OK" button says.

Comment: i understand what you ask, but it cannot be done. there is no way to detect the words from JS. the other thing (besides html modal) you can do is to simply phrase the "question" as a statement that the user agrees with or wants to avoid. so, you shouldn't ask a question in the dialog text, and you shouldn't need to name buttons; it should be obvious. for example, don't say "Press Aceptar to proceed or Cancelar to cancel", but rather say "Proceding to next section...!", which when even poorly translated can suggest that i click "Aceptar" or "OK" if i want to advance. buttons always ==ok/cancel

Comment: @dandavis: ok, you say this can't be done. You may wish to write this as an answer?